# Material Icons ligatures electron OSX

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, electron, google-material-icons

I am trying to use Google Material Icons in an electron app and ran across an issue in rendering the icons.  The icons render perfectly on Windows but not on OSX. Using devtools I have seen that both request the font as 'woff2' format successfully but only Windows appears to render the icon...OSX simply list the ligature text.

Windows (left), OSX (right)

[image: Windows]
[image: OSX]

These works in Windows build but not OSX...it simply lists `home` or `&#xE88A;`

```
<i class="material-icons">home</i>
<i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i>
```

I have also tried

```
<i class="material-icons" id="test"></i>
#test:after{ content: 'home' }
```

Not sure if this an issue with chromium build for OSX, a OS font issue, or what?  If anyone could provide any guidance on some things to try I would really appreciate the help.

Here is the CSS being used

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(./fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(./fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(./fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff) format('woff'),
       url(./fonts/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not 100% sure on what the issue is but wanted to post an update if it could help anyone else.

On my Windows build I had a font installed `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf`...once I copied it and then uninstalled it, the Windows app stopped rendering correctly.

I then copied the `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf` to the fonts folder in my electron project and then updated my css to look like

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Now it seems to be working...Not sure if there was something wrong with the other font sets or if I have some css setup incorrectly.